# python -m SimpleHTTPServer - Listening on 0.0.0.0:8000 but “Page Not Found”

Tags: python, port, simplehttpserver

When I use this code

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

it is showing

```
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

But page is not displaying.

When I used the port 80

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80
```

it is working.

How to enable the port 8000

Anyone can help me with solution to this.

When I am using my own IP its working but in ssh connection  port 8000 is not working only port 80 is working

Comment: Stupid question, but did you use the right port when connecting also?

Comment: ya I used right port

Answer (score 1):

```
http://0.0.0.0:8000
```

Should do the work.

The default port when browsing HTTP from a Web-Browser is 80. If you want to browser from a different port you have to specify it after the site address with leading colon.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the port in your browser (80 is the default port)

Try http:\0.0.0.0:8000\ instead of http:\0.0.0.0\

Answer (score 0):

I used to change my cloud server settings
 I gave permission to access ports 7000-9000
Now it is working